# Kendo grid detailInit access to parent grid

Tags: jquery, user-interface, grid, kendo-ui, hierarchy

I have master grid which contains child grid that contains another child grid. And I have custom command in 3rd child, when i clicked to, I want to extract some cells from master grid. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well here comes the power of jQuery. You will need to go some traversal to find the masterRow and thus get the [dataItem](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-dataItem) of the masterGrid.

something like this (I named each element to make it clearer):

```
var thirdLevelGrid = $(yourCommandButtonHtmlElement).closest('.k-grid');
var secondLevelGrid = thirdLevelGrid.parents('.k-grid');
var topDetailRow = secondLevelGrid.closest('tr');
var topMasterRow = topDetailRow.prev();
var masterGrid = $('#nameOfTHeMasterGrid').data().kendoGrid;
var andFinallyTheModelWeWereWaitingFor = masterGrid.dataItem(topMasterRow);
```

Of course you can chain this to look more fancy or optimize in some way.

I hope this helps you get the idea.

Comment: How can I get a direct reference to the child grid, so that I can set some values to the current row of the child grid?

Comment: Saved me copious amounts of time! Perfect